# How to save the testcafe studio run configuration into a JSON

Tags: testcafe

Is there a way to save the run configurations into a JSON file?

I maintain the run configuration in a .testcaferc.json file and would like to extract the configuration into a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe Studio stores its settings in JSON, but it uses its own format to store them, including all run configuration settings. You can't migrate settings from one product to another by coping their setting files.